# Unable to extract attribute value with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```py
caller = driver.find_element_by_id("sys_display.new_call.caller") 
print(caller.get_attribute('value'))
```

[image: HTML CODE]

Hello running into issues when trying to extract a attribute value from a element.
I have tried using `caller= driver.find_element_by_id("sys_display.new_call.caller").get_attribute('value')`
but it doesnt seem to pull the value at all from HTML.

I am a noobie thanks for the help!

Comment: could you add the screen shot of the value you are trying to extract

Comment: Please add the URL that you're trying to extract data?

Comment: the value I would like to extract is MyMercy User

Answer (score 0):

To print the value of the *value* attribute i.e. `MyMercy User` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id^='sys_display'][id*='new_call'][id$='caller'][data-name='caller']").get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='sys_display.new_call.caller' and @data-name='caller']").get_attribute("value"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id^='sys_display'][id*='new_call'][id$='caller'][data-name='caller']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.temporary-mail.net/')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='sys_display.new_call.caller' and @data-name='caller']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  MyMercy User
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: @PDHide Let's discuss the issue in details within [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium)

Comment: So these keep giving me an error of: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/jjudi/OneDrive/Documents/Python Scripts/import selenium.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id^='sys_display'][id*='new_call'][id$='caller'][data-name='caller']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  File "C:\Users\jjudi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @Justin.U Pretty much expected as you haven't provided the text based HTML which would have helped us to test our own solution before publishing.

Comment: Sorry its not a public site so I dont want to release to much information on it. I do appreciate the help tho, Do I need to specify that its in main?

Answer (score -1):

In selenium if the value is stored as innerText, you have to retrive it using .text method , this works only if the element is visible in the UI. Means if its hidden or out of view port .text method will return blank. In that case you could use get attribute "textContent" . But for testing textCOntent is not recommended as it won't validate if the text is displaye in UI. It is recommended only for web scraping

You can also wait for value field to have the text before printing you are indeed looking for value attribute

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
caller = wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID, 'sys_display.new_call.caller'),"MyMercy User"))

caller = driver.find_element_by_id("sys_display.new_call.caller") 
print(caller.get_attribute('value'))
print(caller.text)
print(caller.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Try printing the three values and see which one gives the result you want